# background-image only displays as blank

Tags: javascript, .net, css, visual-studio-2010

I have read through many of the messages on the site regarding proper path references and such when loading a CSS background-image but haven't been able to resolve this issue.
My CSS reference is:

```
.pageLoading
{
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: no-repeat left top;
   background-image: url(<%=ResolveUrl('~/Resources/loading.gif')%>);
}
```

I am affecting this change through a button `OnClientClick="HideContent();"` which executes the following JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("<%=Master.PageLoadingDivTag.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
```

When I click the button the content of the page disappears only to replaced by a blank form.  The behavior is the same regardless of which image I use.
All files (Site.Master, Site.css, and loading.gif) are in the same Resources directory so it should be able to reference these without an issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If they're all in the same directory then just try background-image: url(loading.gif');

Comment: That was my first attempt but I gradually added more and more to the reference because it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the CSS description I had set the height and width to 100%.  Based upon the placement of the  tag it was actually displaying but I just couldn't see it.  I set an absolute value for the dimensions and now it works fine.
Thanks!